# Does it makes sense to run preliminary analysis on the dependent variable before running linear regression?

Tags: regression, self-study, linear-model

I am working on an assignment. I have a cross-sectional sample containing 25 observation. The model is really simple, only consisting one independent variable y and one dependent variable x. It is requested to compute the histogram, the boxplot and the Q-Q plot of the data. My question is whether it makes sense to run these preliminary analysis on the dependent variable x.

Comment: Not really, except for quality control.   But sometimes you see strong asymmetry in x that makes it more likely to predict y linearly if you pre-transform x to make it more symmetric.  But you don't know for sure because it's the x-y relationship that matters (and for which assuming linearity is usually a mistake).

Comment: Thank you. One thing it's not really clear, what do you mean for asymmetry? And how can I check it for x?

Comment: Make a histogram of x and see if one of the tails is extremely long.  If so you might have overly influential observations and may have a lower chance of a linear relationship with y.  General solution in that case is to fit a regression spline to predict y from a behavior-enhancing transformation of x such as cube root (lots of people take logs for heavy right tail but this doesn't handle x=0).   Keep in mind that if you just want to assess association, use a rank correlation measure and be done with it.